# Examples of PIDs that are not Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, principal-ideal-domains

If $R=\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{-19})]$ is an example of a PID which is not a Euclidean domain. But since Euclidean domains may not necessarily be fields, this doesn't say much unless $R$ in this case or in other cases is a field. Is $R$ a field? What are ways to check if a PID is a field?

What are some examples of PIDs that are not fields?

Comment: Example: $\Bbb Z$ is a PID, but not a field.

Comment: Many, many, yea, infinitely many. $k[t]$ for an indeterminate $t$ and $k$ a field. $k[[t]]$. $\Bbb Z$. $\Bbb Z[1/n]$ for any nonzero integer $n$.

Comment: [DaRT search for nonfield PIDs](http://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/search/results/?H=1&H=65l&L=54).

Comment: @rschwieb wow great resource. Thanks!